# Unit tests for request-promise-native using Sinon

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

How can I write a unit test for this method?

```
import { CoreOptions, UriOptions } from 'request';
import requestPromise from 'request-promise-native';

export class Client {

    public async post(request: CoreOptions & UriOptions) {
        return requestPromise.post(request)
    }  
}
```

I get an error with my unit test code. (*RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000*). How can I resolve it?

```
import { Client } from '../source/http/Client';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import requestPromise from 'request-promise-native';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('Client', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const client = new Client();
    const response = {};
    const postStub = sinon.stub(requestPromise, 'post').resolves(mResponse);
    const actual = await client.post({ uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api', method: 'POST' });
    expect(actual).to.be.equal(response);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(postStub, { uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api', method: 'POST' });
  });
});
```

What's incorrect in my code? I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sinon.stub` to make a stub for `requestPromise.post` method.  E.g.

`client.ts`:

```js
import { CoreOptions, UriOptions } from 'request';
import requestPromise from 'request-promise-native';

export class Client {
  public async post(request: CoreOptions & UriOptions) {
    return requestPromise.post(request);
  }
}
```

`client.test.ts`:

```js
import { Client } from './client';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import requestPromise from 'request-promise-native';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('61384662', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const client = new Client();
    const mResponse = {};
    const postStub = sinon.stub(requestPromise, 'post').resolves(mResponse);
    const actual = await client.post({ uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api', method: 'GET' });
    expect(actual).to.be.equal(mResponse);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(postStub, { uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api', method: 'GET' });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  61384662
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (262ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 client.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/61384662

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work with request-promise-native.

Comment: @DarkinRall It works fine for me. You can check the source code.

Comment: Hm, it's strange. But I get error while test: RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: @DarkinRall Can you show me the test code? Please edit your post and paste your test code.